# Active Directory Authentication With C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a serious problem authenticating my user against AD. I can use the PrincipalContext way or the DirectoryEntry way and check whether login was successful or not. But this is not enough for my case. I need to know why authentication failed(eg: password expiration, account locked, bad password count limit). Is there anyway of achieving this without using native win32 dll's. By the way this may not be a web project all the time. My optimal solution could be a generic one. 
Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

You should get the reason for the error in the exception.

Regardles of that you get the information if authentication **will fail** by using the PrincipalContext members like:

- AccountExpirationDate (is the account expired)
- AccountLockoutTime (is the account locked)
- Enabled (is the account enabled)
- IsAccountLockedOut (is the account locked)
- PermittedLogonTimes (is the user allowed to login now)
- PermittedWorkstations (is the user allowed to login from this client)